# Hide soft keyboard for editText focus/touch

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am trying to hide the soft keyboard from showing when an EditText either receives focus or a touch event.  I want the EditText to be editable - there will be text in the EditText, so I want the EditText to respond to a touch event so the cursor is positioned, but I will have dedicated buttons for editing rather than using the soft keyboard.  I can't get this to work - the soft keyboard seems to pop up on both focuschange and touch events.

I have reduced the code to the following:

AndroidMainifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="App1.App1" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application android:label="App1">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" 
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

  <EditText xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/editText" />

  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.cs:

```
namespace App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            LinearLayout layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout);
            layout.FocusChange += FocusChange;

            EditText editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText);
            editText.FocusChange += FocusChange;
            editText.Touch += Touch;

            AdView adView = FindViewById<AdView>(Resource.Id.adView);
            var requestbuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
            adView.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());
        }


        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            AdView adView = FindViewById<AdView>(Resource.Id.adView);
            if (adView != null)
                adView.Resume();
        }


        private void FocusChange(object sender, View.FocusChangeEventArgs e)
        {
            InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            im.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Window.DecorView.WindowToken, Android.Views.InputMethods.HideSoftInputFlags.None);

            LinearLayout layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout);
            im.HideSoftInputFromWindow(layout.WindowToken, Android.Views.InputMethods.HideSoftInputFlags.None);

            EditText editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText);
            im.HideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.WindowToken, Android.Views.InputMethods.HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        }



        private void Touch(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
            im.HideSoftInputFromWindow(Window.DecorView.WindowToken, Android.Views.InputMethods.HideSoftInputFlags.None);

            LinearLayout layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout);
            im.HideSoftInputFromWindow(layout.WindowToken, Android.Views.InputMethods.HideSoftInputFlags.None);

            EditText editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText);
            im.HideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.WindowToken, Android.Views.InputMethods.HideSoftInputFlags.None);

            (sender as EditText).OnTouchEvent(e.Event);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried variations of many stackoverflow answers to hide the keyboard, but nothing works.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with a tricky solution, it works, but i don't like it.

I have a simple layout with a `EditText` and a `Button`. When you press the button I add a "*" to the `EditText` were the cursor is. You can manipulate the cursor with the finger and the soft keyboard never opens because *when the EditText gets focus I hide the keyboard*.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText  android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text Here"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/myButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click Me!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the code in the `Activity`:

```cs
public class MainActivity : Activity, View.IOnTouchListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        EditText edt = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.myEditText);
        edt.SetOnTouchListener(this);

        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
        button.Click += delegate { edt.Text = edt.Text.Insert(edt.SelectionStart, "*"); };
    }

    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        // Pass the event to the edit text to have the blinking cursor.
        v.OnTouchEvent(e);
        // Hide the input.
        var imm = ((InputMethodManager)v.Context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService));
        imm?.HideSoftInputFromWindow(v.WindowToken, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Final result

[image]

Comment: I just tested my first solution in emulator and it worked. But in device it failed. I updated my answer with a working solution. Try it here: https://github.com/jzeferino/stackoverflow-38956548

Comment: Thanks again - I really appreciate your help. That works, but if I add an AdView then I have the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940162/hide-soft-keyboard-on-app-resume/38940401?noredirect=1#comment65239161_38940401.  If I add an AdView to your test code, and implement the solution you gave in the link above, when I switch apps and resume the soft keyboard pops up.  I'm beginning to wonder if the behaviours I want are mutually exclusive...

Comment: zip file on dropbox here https://www.dropbox.com/s/uvwomyb5b9teofr/archive.zip?dl=0   Deploy that app to a phone, run the app, switch to another app, then switch back and the soft keyboard pops up.  Comment out the line "adView.LoadAd(requestbuilder.Build());" in onCreate and the soft keyboard doesn't pop up - but I want the banner ad.  I don't get it.  You've done a great job answering my questions - I just can't make the answers work together.  Thanks again.

Comment: Since your problem ins't in the ambit of the question my answer will be written here. I added the `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to the layout root and removed the focus from the edittext when activity goes onpause: `protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
            edt.ClearFocus();
        }` 
Please take a look at my github, i added a new project with it there. Oh and btw your Google Ads import were incorrent. Chek My git solution thanks. (remove old comments here please)

Comment: Fantastic!  problem solved.  My thanks to you for your knowledge, efforts and persistence with my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @jzeferino I see this is for Android and it does not show soft keyboard at all.  I wonder why in Xamarin.Android, the soft keyboard still shows briefly, then gets clossed by call to InputMethodManager HideSoftInputFromWindow?  I am also passing HideSoftInputFlags.None (or 0) but keyboard still shows briefly

Comment: @pixel this is for Xamarin.Android but it will work on Android off course. Is your problem the same as the OP?

Comment: @jzeferino I am using Xamarin.Forms and creating custom renderers that will set HideSoftInputFlags to None (or 0).  The problem is that I dont see in your gif above if keyboard shows or not since the git shows only the EntryField and Button but not the bottom of the screen where keyboard would be visible.  So, I assume, your solution works but giff does not show that.  I assume this works on Android, maybe Xamarin.Android as you say too, but I dont see it working in Xamarin.Forms in which case, the keyboard will show up briefly, then get closed.  I dont know what do you mean by 'OP'?

Comment: My code is for Xamarin.Android. So it work on Xamarin.Android. I will work on Android too. And regarding Xamarin.Forms it will work, BUT, if your'e doing it inside a render then maybe something is messing with the inout.

Comment: @jzeferino I have provided code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53490262/xamarin-forms-entry-that-should-not-show-softkeyboard-on-its-focus. Any idea why it is not working?  Thanks